# Wordpress - Code Snippet Library not working on my theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, code-snippets

Hi I am working on a new Wordpress blog and it for code tutorials so it's very important to have code snippets in it , I tried many plugins but I comfortable with [Code Snippet Library](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippet-library/)

The issue is it's not working on my custom theme I tried twenty fifteen, twenty fourteen and twenty thirteen and it work great on all of them,

How I know the part in my theme that conflict with the plugin, or what I have to add to my theme to support this plugin.

EDIT - what I have done:

1- I downloaded the plugin from  [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippet-library/) .

2- then uploaded it in my plugins folder and unzipped it.

3- go to admin panel and activate the plugin.

4- go to code snippet menu and added a new snippet.

5- get the shortcode of the snippet and use it in my post.

the result is the code get displayed but without any theming or code highlighting  from the plugin.

the expected result is [image]

and that what I get when go and edit the snippet 
EDIT- here is the [link of my blog page](http://w34.co/chapters/1-getting-start-with-angularjs/)

Comment: the code snippet library plugin doesn't work on my theme

Comment: I think you should add more information what have you done because your post is too broad.Many will assume that you have forgotten to activate your the plugin.

Comment: thanks for your help, I added the steps I followed in the edit section of the question.

Comment: Its actually highligted.. grayish color.

Comment: check the screenshot please

Comment: [base on the plugins other notes you can change theme of the snippet](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippet-library/other_notes/) by going to Code Snippets > Settings

Comment: I already changed the theme and selected the dark blue one which is appear when I edit the snippet, and remember that every thing is working great with the other themes comes with wordpress

Comment: Have you changed Theme for front-end snippet display:? and if you have change it have you coppied the short code of the code snippet you have created and pasted it your post?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102332/discussion-between-peter-wilson-and-jameshwart-lopez).

Comment: thanks to @jameshwartlopez it's working now. I forgot to add wp_footer(); function :( . thank you for you help and time.